# Generalised Func wrapping with Anonymous Values equivalent to AutoFixture 'With'

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, autofixture

In an AutoFixture-based test, I'm trying to express as cleanly as possible the following:

*When I pass `<input>` to the parameter `x` of this method, filling in the other parameters anonymously, the result is...*

Taking the example of a factory method:-

```
class X
{
    public static X Create( Guid a, Guid b, Guid c, String x, String y);
```

I'm trying to express as a succinct series of tests:

1. If I pass null for `x`, it should throw
2. If I pass null for `y`, it should throw

In order to express I can say:

```
var fixture = Fixture();
var sut = default( Func<Guid, Guid, Guid,string,X>);
sut = fixture.Get( ( Guid anonA, Guid anonB, Guid anonC, string anonY ) => 
    x =>
        X.Create( anonA, anonB, anonC, x, anonY ) );

Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>( () => sut( null));
```

For the second instance, which is only slightly different, I need to do:

```
var fixture = Fixture();
var sut = default( Func<Guid, Guid, Guid,string,X> );
sut = fixture.Get( ( Guid anonA, Guid anonB, Guid anonC, string anonX ) => 
    y =>
        X.Create( anonA, anonB, anonC, anonX, y ) );
Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>( () => sut( null));
```

For properties, there's `With` in AutoFixture. Is there an eqivalent for method (and/or ctor) arguments ?

PS 0. I don't mind if its necessary to get into 'magic' strings for this case - i.e., having the `x` bit be `"x"`.

PS 1. The other elephant in the room is that I'm bumping my head against the 4x overloads of `Get` in AutoFixture - or is that because I have an old version in this environment?

PS 2. Also open to better suggestions as to how to model this - as long as they deal with the fact that I want it to be a method invocation and not properties or fields (and I'd like it to work in an AutoFixture stylee).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really isn't any feature in AutoFixture that makes this easier, but I'm open to suggestions. However, I don't see how you could express something like that in a strongly typed fashion. What would the syntax look like?

However, if you only need this for testing that Null Guards work, you can use AutoFixture.Idioms for that.

Here's an example.

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
var assertion = new GuardClauseAssertion(fixture);
var method = typeof(GuardedMethodHost).GetMethod("ConsumeStringAndInt32AndGuid");
assertion.Verify(method);
```

If you look at [the source code of `Ploeh.AutoFixture.IdiomsUnitTest.Scenario`](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/IdiomsUnitTest/Scenario.cs) you'll find other examples, but I admit it's one of the more poorly documented areas of AutoFixture...

Another thing entirely is that methods with few (or no) parameters are better than methods with many parameters, so have you considered Introducing a Parameter Object?

Comment: +1 Thanks. The idiom you suggest pretty much nails what I'm after. Have previously spent some time perusing the Idioms stuff - like AF, it's all obvious once you've gotten up the initial learning molehill so while I had a vague idea something like this was in there, I didnt connect the dots other than to know I need to get an @ploeh gaze on the issue. You have a point on the relevance of Introduce Parameter Object and there's certainly other cases where the restriction forced the issue which is what you want. However the current me would argue for somewhere 6-8 as the dividing line more than 4

Comment: i.e. having overloads with up to 16 would def be a bad signal. The other issue is that that's a circular argument - I'd be back to square one with having to TDD in guard clauses into my PO class/struct.

Comment: <strike>On reflection, I guess if I did a Build with an explicit `ICustomization` in the chain which intercepts Specimen creation for a top level parameter named `x`, returning a given value/Func result. Then all I need is to hold my nose while C# forces me to write out longhand `.FromFactory<Guid, Guid, Guid, String, String)>( X.Create)`. ... so is there anything I should be aware of that plays in that space? </strike>. Doh, it's all orthogonal; the `Register...FromFactory` is how you bring in Factory Methods and the Idiom is how you exercise guards - no combining required.

Comment: That leaves me with a desire for the max overloaded type param count on `FromFactory` (and possibly some other related methods) to go up to 8 as I want to be able to Register a factory methods which are borderline (before they get Introduce Parameter Objected into cleanliness). Does that make sense as an <strike>issue</strike>pull request or do you feel the core should stay opinionated at 4 and have people maintain more parameterful overloads as extension methods elsewhere. In the meantime, thanks for teddybearing once again during this comment splurge.

Comment: There are a couple of reasons why FromFactory is limited to 4 input parameters. The original reason was that AutoFixture is still compiled on .NET 3.5, so Func with 4 parameters is the largest predefined delegate. While I could have created custom delegates, I actually do find it a very appropriate limit. As Uncle Bob writes in Clean Code, one parameter is good, but zero is even better. With that perspective, 4 is already quite too much, so I see no reason to support anything more.

Comment: Still, if you need it, you can always create a custom ISpecimenBuilder that acts as an Adapter over a larger Func, and then use the FromFactory(ISpecimenBuilder) overload, so there's still a way out for you.

Comment: Both strands of your argument are individually strong enough so no argument here. Will have a play with the overload you mention, thanks.