# How to verify that automapper mappings have been created for all uses?

Tags: c#, automapper, roslyn

I'd like to have a test that verifies that, for each use of `Automapper.Mapper.Map<T1,T2>()`, that there is a corresponding mapping configuration (`AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<T1,T2>()`) in my Bootstrapper.

I was just about to go down the road of using [Roslyn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Roslyn) to interface with the compiler and find all usages of the `Map<>` method and then try to map using those instances. Although that would do the trick, I think I'd rather use something that already exists.

Does this exist? If not, is there a better way to do this than with Roslyn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're treading too deep into meta-programming.

Best thing you can do is to contain your mapped classes to one or several namespaces, and check that there are mappings for all classes in those namespaces. For this you won't need Roslyn, Cecil or any such thing.

If you're abandoning compile-time checks, at least you have to put in place some conventions, and if your conventions are well defined, you can verify them.

Comment: +1 [An example of the sort of thing you might do with verification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452539/generalised-func-wrapping-with-anonymous-values-equivalent-to-autofixture-with/11455580#11455580)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you can't be sure - there are loads of cases where it's not deterministic (e.g. a model of type `Y` might be passed to AutoMapper downcast to an `object`.

You should provide coverage of the actual consumption of the mappings as part of your normal code coverage.

Whether that means unit tests for every mapping method is a different question...