# is there a way to write a generic unit test for multiple null arg validations for a single method?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, xunit, xunit.net

I have a method with 4 string parameters.  A null parameter validation guard exists for each of these parameters. Is there a way to write a *single* xUnit null validation unit test to generically test all 4 of these parameters?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15083283/11635

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, this doesn't seem like a very useful thing to do. :-) However...

In NUnit, you could do something like the following

```
[TestCase(null, "b", "c", "d")]
[TestCase("a", null, "c", "d")]
[TestCase("a", "b", null, "d")]
[TestCase("a", "b", "c", null)]
public void NullArgDetected(string a, string b, string c, string d)
{
    // call method and assert that it throws
}
```

You would, of course have to change the types of the arguments to match the method you are calling. In case that type is not allowed by C# as an Attribute constructor argument, you would need to use `[TestCaseSource]` rather than `[TestCase`].

Personally, I might do this if I had 10 arguments. For four, I would just write four separate test methods.